# i want to search for a child in database then remove it but it won't work here

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

i want to search for a specific user in the ref(likers) then remove it but it won't work here and it alert "likers" when i alert(this.liker) not the user key in the ref(user)

here is the database

[image]

and here is the code

```
firebase.database().ref('posts/-M13xC_yeIsj342A75pz/likers')
            .orderByChild('user')
            .equalTo('fHI1izTOJ5VeC7ZnjXUducickzj1'/* 'PCrBx38NcjZdsgmRS805sk7lgWn1' firebase.auth().currentUser || {}).uid */)
            .on('value', snap => {
               this.liker =  snap.key
               alert(this.liker)
            })
            firebase.database().ref('posts').child(this.props.postKey/*'-M0IviCqMGE_PxoqNd0W'*/).child('likers').child(key).remove()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

You code need to handle this fact, by looping over the child nodes of the snapshot you get.

```
firebase.database().ref('posts/-M13xC_yeIsj342A75pz/likers')
        .orderByChild('user')
        .equalTo('fHI1izTOJ5VeC7ZnjXUducickzj1'/* 'PCrBx38NcjZdsgmRS805sk7lgWn1' firebase.auth().currentUser || {}).uid */)
        .once('value', results => {
           results.forEach((snapshot) => {
               alert(snapshot.key)
           });
        })
```

In the above, I also changed the code to use `once` instead of `on`. This won't make any difference to the query results, but means it stops listening after it gets the query results.